# Xamarin Android - unable to see textview in preview

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

Shouldn´t I be able to see TextView from right on the preview on the left?

[image]

Comment: The `Xamarin.Android Designer` should be supported on Xamarin.Android. You could try to delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuild. If this does not work, close it and restart the VS.

Answer (score 0):

Enable accelerated rendering setting was the issue:

[image]